# File input returning null value in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a file input element on my laravel and it is returning a null value. I have tried var_dump and dd() to see the values returned on form post and it returns null. I have also read similar questions and tried to apply several of the suggested solutions to my problem yet i have had no luck finding the solution.

I have even checked the max upload size for my wamp server and the file size of the images i am trying to upload are all in kilobytes and no where close to even 1mb.

what could i be doing wrong?

this is my view

```
  <div class="container">
      <a href=""> Edit This Page </a>
        {{ Form::open( array('route' => 'postSiteTest', 'files' => true)) }}
         {{Form::file('testLink')}}
        {{ Form::token() }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary   btn-lg">
      {{ Form::close() }}
  </div>
```

and this is my controller

```
public function postSiteTest()
{
    $file = Input::file('testLink');
    var_dump($file);

    $test = new FacilitiesPg();
    $file1 = Input::file('testlink');
    $fileName1 = $file1->getClientOriginalName();

    $test->libImgLink = $fileName1;
    if($test->save())
    {
        return 'img name saved';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending many hours trying to fix this error, I discovered that the problem was from the value of "post_max_size" property in the php.ini file. I was uploading files that exceeded the amount specified in the php.ini file during file post. Increasing the "post_max_size" solved this problem. 
I hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

i think this line:

```
$file1 = Input::file('testlink');
```

should be change to:

```
$file1 = Input::file('testLink');
```

and also you can use this code for submit button instead for HTML code:

```
{{Form::submit('Save Changes' , array('class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block'))}}
```